# How do I load and save an image from an SQL Server database using GDI+ and C++?

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, image, gdi+

I need specifically to load a JPG image that was saved as a blob. GDI+ makes it very easy to retrieve images from files but not from databases...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Image::Image(IStream *, BOOL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535410(VS.85).aspx).  This takes a pointer to a COM object implementing the IStream interface.  You can get one of these by allocating some global memory with [GlobalAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366574(VS.85).aspx) and then calling [CreateStreamOnHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378980(VS.85).aspx) on the returned handle.  It'll look something like this:

```
shared_ptr<Image> CreateImage(BYTE *blob, size_t blobSize)
{
    HGLOBAL hMem = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE,blobSize);
    BYTE *pImage = (BYTE*)::GlobalLock(hMem);

    for (size_t iBlob = 0; iBlob < blobSize; ++iBlob)
        pImage[iBlob] = blob[iBlob];

    ::GlobalUnlock(hMem);

    CComPtr<IStream> spStream;
    HRESULT hr = ::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hMem,TRUE,&spStream);

    shared_ptr<Image> image = new Image(spStream);  
    return image;
}
```

But with error checking and such (omitted here to make things clearer)

Comment: That's what I get for not trying to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

First fetch your blog into a byte array then use something like this:

```
public static Image CreateImage(byte[] pict)
{
   System.Drawing.Image img = null;
   using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(pict)) {
    img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
   }
   return img;
}
```

Comment: what's the equivalent of MemoryStream on C++?

Comment: I originally misread the title and thought you were looking for C#. It appears MemoryStream is available in C++ too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(VS.71).aspx